# SQL Server ORDER BY seems surprisingly slow

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

Original query:

```
SELECT V.Date, V.Amount, I.Number
FROM Values V 
JOIN Items I ON V.ItemId = I.Id AND I.AssetId = V.AssetId
WHERE I.Type IN (10023, 10025) AND V.AssetId = 100
ORDER BY V.Date
```

Times out after some long time. After poking about a bit, I commented out the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT V.Date, V.Amount, I.Number
FROM Values V 
JOIN Items I ON V.ItemId = I.Id AND I.AssetId = V.AssetId
WHERE I.Type IN (10023, 10025) AND V.AssetId = 100
--ORDER BY V.Date
```

This returns two rows in zero millis.

I was under the impression that order by against a JOIN would occur after the query was complete, that is, it would make a temp (name?) table for the results and then order them. Apparently this impression is wrong.

Any suggestions? I don't have SHOWPLAN (et all) on this server, so I'm a bit in the dark.

Comment: Without an execution plan, or the table definitions with indexes and approximate row counts nobody can help you. Any suggestions would be guesswork.

Comment: One thing you can try even without any special permissions or further analysis: see if adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the first query makes any difference. This will at least circumvent any stale cached execution plan, if that's an issue. If this doesn't make a difference, then most trivial rewrites of this query should not make any difference either. (This is important to know because you might otherwise think you've "solved" the issue, when really you've just temporarily postponed it until the new query also gets a bad plan at some point.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I'll try that today!

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` can affect the execution plan.  If the query does indeed only return two rows, then the timeout is surprising.

I would rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT V.Date, V.Amount, I.Number
FROM Values V  JOIN
     Items I
     ON V.ItemId = I.Id AND I.AssetId = V.AssetId
WHERE I.Type IN (10023, 10025) AND I.AssetId = 100
-----------------------------------^ the only change
ORDER BY V.Date;
```

Then the best indexes are `Items(AssetId, Type, Id, Number)` and `Values(ItemId, Assetid, Date, Amount)`.  These are covering indexes for the query.

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if that makes a difference -- the optimizer is typically clever enough to see `I.AssetId` and `V.AssetId` are the same based on the `JOIN`, so which one you end up using should make no difference. I'm with Sean on this one: there could be quite a few things wrong, from a stale query plan to outdated statistics to a skewed histogram for the values used here, and without plans it's hard if not impossible to tell what's what.

Comment: As Jeroen surmised, this had no effect on the performance. I would still like to get to the bottom of this, but in the meantime I'm doing the sort in my .Net code instead of SQL and that is getting things going.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz . . . With the stated indexes, this had no impact on performance?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to troubleshoot without an execution plan.

First thing I would do is to make sure statistics are up to date. If stats are not up to date, SQL can produce inefficient plans.

If you cannot do this, you can change your query to force the correct plan.

For example, you can use a table variable to ensure ORDER BY is done last.

```
--declare staging table
declare @stage([Date] date, [Amount] decimal(19,4), [Number] int);

--insert data into staging table
INSERT INTO @stage([Date], [Amount], [Number])
SELECT V.Date, V.Amount, I.Number
FROM Values V 
JOIN Items I ON V.ItemId=I.Id AND I.AssetId=V.AssetId
WHERE I.Type IN (10023, 10025) AND V.AssetId=100) as t1;

--retrieve data from staging table with sorting
SELECT * FROM @stage ORDER BY Date;
```

This is not ideal, but if you don't have DBA permissions it's the best you can do.

Another thing to try is to use the MAXDOP 1 hint. This tells SQL engine not to use parallel execution which sometimes helps avoid inefficient plans.

```
SELECT V.Date, V.Amount, I.Number
FROM Values V 
JOIN Items I ON V.ItemId=I.Id AND I.AssetId=V.AssetId
WHERE I.Type IN (10023, 10025) AND V.AssetId=100) as t1
ORDER BY Date
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

Note that I just added OPTION (MAXDOP 1) to your original query.

Comment: The optimizer isn't fooled by base tricks like this. A subquery will *not* guarantee an order of operations; a trivial subquery like this will just be inlined back, and should yield the exact same plan.

Comment: I've had similar casses where this helped. If not insert into temp table then sort.. MAXDOP 1 hint also helps sometimes.

Comment: Explicitly materializing the results first and tweaking `MAXDOP` are indeed things that definitely make a difference. Using a subquery like this would only help "accidentally", because the query is not exactly the same textually as the original one and will thus get a recompile. But plan-wise, the optimizer will see straight through this. (It would be helpful sometimes If it didn't, so you could choose to explicitly materialize results, but them's the breaks -- even CTEs are inlined.)

Comment: Ok so the query as in the original post did not help, it had a similar delay. I have not used MAXDOP, how would I use that in this case?

Comment: I've changed the answer to use a table variable instead of a sub-query. This should definitely work but be careful to only use this if the record count is small. I've also added an example of how to use MAXDOP option. I don't know if this is going to help...